# Bcrypt laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel

My code is like this :

```
<?php
    $password = '12345';
    echo bcrypt($password);
?>
```

It's not working

Its error is `Fatal error: Call to undefined function bcrypt() in...`

Whether to load library?

Thank you

Comment: Where are you putting this code? The bcrypt function is a helper and should be available in most places in the Laravel context.

Comment: Ideally you should be using PHP's [password API](http://php.net/password) if possible.

Comment: @MarkDavidson, Whether bcrypt function can run on regular files. My intention not in laravel context

Comment: This function is available in `laravel 5.1` and upper version. What version you are using ?

Comment: @Karan I think it is available in 5.0 as well, according to the docs but he may be using laravel 4.*.

Comment: @mosestoh Yes it can run in regular files but how does it know about it? Are you including it or autoloading it in someway?

Comment: @mosestoh Give `Hash::make` a shot, it should in Laravel 4 + 5 produce a bcrypt hash anyway.

Comment: @Karan, I use laravel 5.0

Comment: @MarkDavidson, I did not enter a any file. what files that must be loaded?

Comment: @Matt, It does not work. Whether to load library?

Comment: @moses, this function is not available in `laravel 5.0`, check http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#miscellaneous. Use `Hash::make('12345')` instead

Comment: As others suggested, try `Hash::make('12345');` and check it with `Hash::check('12345', $hash)`. Also you might need to include `use Hash;` in your controller

Comment: I use php native. I do not use laravel. but I want to call a function bcript in laravel. if it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1591777), you can use the following:

```
<?php
$password = '12345';
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do it this way**

```
echo password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```